# GCP Terraform google_project_iam_member does not remove manually added roles to a memeber

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

i am using google_project_iam_member to add roles such as "roles/bigquery.dataOwner" to users and when i change the role on the terraform file, the roles do get changed but issue is with manual changes. For e.g if i create a user with "roles/bigquery.dataOwner" and then someone adds/Changes the role to "Owner", the next run of terraform does not remove "Owner" but just adds "roles/bigquery.dataOwner" . Is there a different module or a way to make sure only the roles specified in terraform is attached to a user and the other ones are removed ?